# Google sheet Countif 10 consecutive days

Tags: google-sheets

I have attendance data as  follows[image: attendance]

I would like to fill the first cell on the third row by counting the adjacent columns from 05-Jan to 24-Jan if there is more than 10 consecutive days of value 6. I would like to copy the formula for the remaining rows as well.

Thanks for any help rendered.

I have been trying but getting nowhere close.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=10<reduce(0, B2:G2, lambda(acc, v, if(v=6, acc+1, if(acc>10, acc, 0))))
```

Comment: Works just fine. Great learning it. Thank you so much.

Comment: The above formula returns the value as TRUE. Can you modify to return the date from the date row where acc turns 11. 

Thank you once again.

Comment: This would require tracking of both the sequential counter and position.  You could try this formula: `=let(result, reduce({0, 0}, C2:T2, lambda(acc, v, if(index(acc, 1)>10, acc, if(v=6, {index(acc, 1)+1, index(acc, 2)+1}, {0, index(acc, 2)+1})))), if(index(result, 1)>10, index(C1:T1, index(result, 2)), ))` where `C2:T2` is the row with numbers, and `C1:T1` is the header row with dates.

Comment: It's nothing less than magic. How did you do it? Can you suggest any learning? Works wonderfully. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked.  Could you mark the question as resolved, please, so other people see it as such.  As to the learning, I would recommend googling "Ben Collins sheets" - he has great posts and advice.  I also have a website that you can find on my profile page.